# Leer entrada de console.log en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, navegador-web

Estoy tratando de capturar la entrada de datos atraves de console.log sin usar node js.
Pero salta el error de readline no esta definida.
Algun otro metodo o donde tengo el error, queria indagar antes de preguntar pero en todos lados usan node creo que para algo tan sencillo tal vez no sea necesario nodeJs.

```
console.log("what's your name!");
var input = readline();
console.log("Hi ! "+input);
```

Comment: el console.log no es el problema es la función readline(), no la esta encontrando en tu js, eso indica el error, como tienes definida el readline?

Comment: readline es una función que tienes en tu js o lo has puesto porque debería hacer algo por defecto?

Comment: para lo que querés hacer te recomiendo que uses la función prompt() !